# upload file different destinations based on the api post call

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am new to Express js. I have two upload buttons and two separate post call to upload the file. I want to upload files to different locations based on the api call.

First post api is /app/upload1
Second post api is /app/upload2

I have multer object with diskstorage.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage(
{
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, FILE_PATH},
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
}
```

Currently, files are stored at the global path.

I want to change the multer such that :
with api call **/app/upload1** - file should be stored in upload1 directory & 
with api call **/app/upload2** - file should be stored in upload2 directory

Can someone please help here.

Comment: My app post call is like below : app.post('/api/v1/file-upload1', upload.single('fil'), fileUpload.file_upload1) how can I use upload({storage1}) here? I tried by adding this in the above line, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need two storages for two separate endpoints, Try this:

```
var storage1 = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null,'path1'},
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

var storage2 = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'path2'},
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

app.post('/upload1', upload({storage1}))
app.post('/upload2', upload({storage2}))
```

Comment: My app post call is like below :

app.post('/api/v1/file-upload1', upload.single('fil'), fileUpload.file_upload1)

how can I use upload({storage1}) here? I tried by adding this in the above line, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

use options destination to set directory what you want to save:

```
var storage1 = multer.diskStorage(
{
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, '/upload1'},
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
 }
}
var upload1 = multer({ storage: storage1 })
app.post('/app/upload1', upload1, function (req, res, next) {
    // todo
})
// var storage 2 = ...
// var upload2 = multer({ storage: storage2 })
```

refer to [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

thanks.